# How to move Debezium messages in Kafka to both data lake and Redshift

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Currently, we have a Kafka topic of Debezium messages. We want to do two things with these messages:

- transform them into a row-based format in Redshift (we do not want to store the Debezium messages themselves)
- store the messages in a data lake (s3)

Does Kafka come with any connectors to do both of these for us? We want the data lake to be the source of truth of data so I worry about using a connector like the JDBC connector to transform messages using an SMT directly to REdshift and having another connector or process move messages from Kafka to the data lake. IF both are reading from the Kafka topic, then the data lake may not be the source of truth.

If I want the data lake to be the source of truth I should probably design it like so:

```
(backend database) -> Kafka topic (debezium) -> Data lake (s3) -> Kafka topic (perhaps only the after record) -> Redshift.
```

Using 2 kafka topics might be best.

Comment: Why from S3 back into Kafka? If S3 was populated from a topic itself? S3 "datalake" should not be the source of truth; the upstream Kafka topic should be.

Comment: so the kafka has a ttl which could lose records but the data lake is cheap storage forever so that's why I think any data replays or the source should be the data lake (s3)

Comment: You can increase Kafka retention to also store forever, but 7 days is the default... You expect not to consume a record for a whole week? In any case, yes, there is an S3 sink and source connector and JDBC Redshift driver for a sink. What issues are you having with them?